# What is the idiom, proverb for "Little problems often become big problems if no one takes the initiative to correct them"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

What is the idiom, proverb for "Little problems often become big problems if no one takes the initiative to correct them"

Which means in an example that If the employees don’t bother to report a malfunctioning machine or a slip-and-fall hazard, serious injuries could occur – injuries that could have been preventable. Ignoring any hazard can be detrimental to one's business and the safety of their employees.

Comment: You can use *a stitch in time saves nine*.

Comment: This is a duplicate. One instance: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360584/word-or-phrase-for-the-many-minor-things-adding-up-to-something-major-and-not-no/360650#360650

Answer (score 3):

> **[a stitch in time (saves nine)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-stitch-in-time-saves-nine?topic=immediately)** saying 
>   (Cambridge Dictionary) ​
>
> *said to mean that it is better to act or deal with problems immediately, because if you wait and deal with them later, things will
>   get worse and the problems will take longer to deal with*.