# A proverb that expresses the idea that an unaddressed problem will lead to consequences?

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

I'm trying to translate a proverb that roughly translates to "a wound untreated will fester," but I'm having trouble thinking of an English equivalent.

Comment: Excuse me, but is this from a Korean or Chinese proverb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the idiom, proverb for "Little problems often become big problems if no one takes the initiative to correct them"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464596/what-is-the-idiom-proverb-for-little-problems-often-become-big-problems-if-no) OR [Is there any idiom to describe the importance not to let somthing bad happen in the first place?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525243/is-there-any-idiom-to-describe-the-importance-not-to-let-somthing-bad-happen-in/525244#525244)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The idiom [a stitch in time saves nine](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stitch+in+time+saves+nine) describes the situation well:

> Solving a difficulty while it is small may save a great deal of trouble in the end.

or

> A prompt, decisive action taken now will prevent problems later.

Comment: This seems similar, but different, like it is looking at the problem from the opposite angle.

Comment: This is about being careful not to cause a problem, not the consequences of ignoring an external problem.

Comment: @TechInquisitor I disagree; the stitch is necessary because there is already a problem (a tear or hole in a garment); the consequence of not solving it early ("in time") is having a bigger problem later ("nine [stitches]"). A proverb about being careful not to cause a problem would, in this metaphor, describe making sure not to damage the garment so as to never need a stitch. For me, perhaps 'stop keeping your keys in your trouser pockets, and you won't have to eventually fix a hole in every pair of trousers you own'.

Answer (score 22):

One with similar medical overtones is ["an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/an%20ounce%20of%20prevention%20is%20worth%20a%20pound%20of%20cure):

> used to say that it is better and easier to stop a problem, illness, etc., from happening than to stop or correct it after it has started

There is a slight difference in context, though, as this is more about avoiding problems *before* they start rather than addressing them quickly once they appear.

Answer (score 10):

This proverb has a virtually identical meaning. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail.

In conversation one might say just “For want of a nail!”

> For Want of a Nail
> For want of a nail the shoe was lost.
> For want of a shoe the horse was lost.
> For want of a horse the rider was lost.
> For want of a rider the message was lost.
> For want of a message the battle was lost.
> For want of a battle the kingdom was lost.
> And all for the want of a horseshoe nail.

Answer (score 9):

**Nip it in the bud**

to stop something immediately so that it does not become a worse problem ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nip%20(something)%20in%20the%20bud))

The reference is to pruning a tree, as you might in an orchard or garden. Branches in unwanted places should be pruned while they're still buds, so the tree doesn't waste energy growing a branch there, and the resulting scar is small.